# Generating sequences of dates and times across a DST transition

Tags: r, lubridate

What is a good way to generate a sequence of times that cross a DST boundary?

For example,

```
startdst <- ymd_hms("2013-03-10 00:00:00",tz="America/Los_Angeles")
enddst <- ymd_hms("2013-11-03 00:00:00",tz="America/Los_Angeles")
```

creates times at the start of the transition day to and from DST on the west coast of the USA.

```
startday <- startdst + minutes(seq(0,to = 24*60, by = 15))
endday <- enddst + minutes(seq(0,to = 24*60, by = 15))
```

creates instants at 15-minute intervals throughout both days.

That gives me

```
> head(startday,n=16)
 [1] "2013-03-10 00:00:00 PST" "2013-03-10 00:15:00 PST"
 [3] "2013-03-10 00:30:00 PST" "2013-03-10 00:45:00 PST"
 [5] "2013-03-10 01:00:00 PST" "2013-03-10 01:15:00 PST"
 [7] "2013-03-10 01:30:00 PST" "2013-03-10 01:45:00 PST"
 [9] NA                        NA                       
[11] NA                        NA                       
[13] "2013-03-10 03:00:00 PDT" "2013-03-10 03:15:00 PDT"
[15] "2013-03-10 03:30:00 PDT" "2013-03-10 03:45:00 PDT"
```

even though 03:00 PDT is only 15 minutes after 01:45 PST.  IOW, why are elements [9] through [12] there?

Similarly,

```
> head(endday,n=16)
 [1] "2013-11-03 00:00:00 PDT" "2013-11-03 00:15:00 PDT"
 [3] "2013-11-03 00:30:00 PDT" "2013-11-03 00:45:00 PDT"
 [5] "2013-11-03 01:00:00 PDT" "2013-11-03 01:15:00 PDT"
 [7] "2013-11-03 01:30:00 PDT" "2013-11-03 01:45:00 PDT"
 [9] "2013-11-03 02:00:00 PST" "2013-11-03 02:15:00 PST"
[11] "2013-11-03 02:30:00 PST" "2013-11-03 02:45:00 PST"
[13] "2013-11-03 03:00:00 PST" "2013-11-03 03:15:00 PST"
[15] "2013-11-03 03:30:00 PST" "2013-11-03 03:45:00 PST"
```

goes straight from 1:45 PDT to 2:00 PST, even though 75 minutes separates those times.  IOW, what happened to 1:00 PST through 1:45 PST?

Incidentally, lubridate knows that:

```
> diff(endday)
Time differences in mins
 [1] 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 75 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15
[26] 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15
[51] 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15
[76] 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15
attr(,"tzone")
[1] "America/Los_Angeles"
```

How do I get contiguous instants in contiguous entries?

BTW, this is loosely related to [Is there a way to assign DST transitions automatically in lubridate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014757/is-there-a-way-to-assign-dst-transitions-automatically-in-lubridate).

Bill

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [R sequence of dates with lubridate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932132/r-sequence-of-dates-with-lubridate?rq=1), I found an answer:

```
seq(startdst,startdst+hours(4),by="15 min")
seq(enddst,enddst+hours(4),by="15 min")
```

I don't understand why my original approach failed, though; it seems like it should have given the same answer or thrown an error.